# Toolbar title with custom view

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar

I am attempting to show both a title, using setTitle and a custom view in my toolbar.

I am not treating it as an actionbar, instead as nothing more than a view.

I am adding both the titles and custom view in Java

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (title != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

    if (subtitle != null) {
        toolbar.setSubtitle(subtitle);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

    // Add switch view to toolbar
    View switchView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.device_list_switch, null);
    toolbar.addView(switchView);
```

The xml for my switch view is

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/discoverable"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/discoverable"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/discoverable"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/discoverable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/discoverable_switch_label"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/discoverable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/discoverable_switch_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/discoverable_switch_margin_left"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What happens is that the RelativeLayout fills the entire toolbar area and the title isn't visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

If you are not using the Toolbar as an ActionBar, then maybe you could just use a layout.

I used a LinearLayout instead of a Toolbar.

What advantages is Toolbar giving you?

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Although using toolbar will allow me to easily inflate a menu

Comment: MenuInflater menuInflater = next MenuInflater(context);
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

Answer (score -2):

This can be solved by adding your own title (and subtitle, if you need it) text views inside the toolbar alongside your custom view.

But perhaps a better way is to use a second toolbar nested inside the first. That way, all formatting is taken care of for you.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <CustomView... />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```